# OpenCV 4.5.5 building from source with GStreamer failed

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

When I want to build OpenCV 4.5.5 from source with GStreamer, I am getting below error:

```
53>cap_gstreamer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_gst_audio_info_from_caps referenced in function "public: bool __cdecl cv::GStreamerCapture::grabAudioFrame(void)" (?grabAudioFrame@GStreamerCapture@cv@@QEAA_NXZ)
53>D:\opencv\build\bin\Release\opencv_videoio455.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
53>Done building project "opencv_videoio.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Before it works well, but in the new version I am getting this error, I also have updated the [GStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/download/) version to the latest (1.18.5) and again got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently a known issue in this release, and there should already be a patch in the release (?)

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/21393

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/21294

There are efforts to get (some) audio support into OpenCV's `videoio`. This seems to be a side effect of that work.

In general, [**browse the issues**](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues?q=gstreamer+audio) using salient identifiers from your error message. You might find that someone already reported it (like above).

Comment: Thanks from the reply! So is there any temporary solution to come over on this problem till bug officially got fix?